# Successfully installed p4vasp, but cannot use it?

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu in Windows 10, I installed p4vasp using "sudo apt install p4vasp". However, when I type the command p4v, I cannot start and use it. It says "Comman p4v is not found, but can be installed with 'sudo apt install p4vasp'". I checked whether have I installed this package by "apt-cache policy p4vasp", it shows installed.

I have no idea what is the problem? It seems I installed it successfully, but I cannot open it.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.